# Contact-Accout Name Field

Tags: account, permissions, contact

I have created a contact without account name. Now I want to associate that contact with an account and when I click on the **"Account Name"  lookup field**, it is only showing the accounts I own. How I can see all the accounts displayed when I click on the lookup icon? I thought a look up filter is setup but it is not and the org level security is public read/write so I was wondering how I can see all accounts?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't see the Accounts you own, rather you see the Account Records which you have recently viewed.
And No I don't think you can see all account records in that lookup list, you will only see recently viewed ones and will have to search for the ones that are not visible.

Update: Check this idea [Show all records in lookup search](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaview?id=08730000000BpkOAAS)

Comment: This is correct. For performance reasons, only your recently viewed records are shown; otherwise you have to search.

Comment: @sfdc_king you're welcome.  Don't forget to mark the answer as accept if it answers your question.